# Unset all but the last subarray if a value already exists

Tags: php

I have the following array that contains order data. Based on the `order_date`, if a date appears twice in the subarrays then I only want to keep the last instance of the subarray.

So in the example below, 21-02 and 21-04 both appear twice, so I want to remove the subarrays 1 and 4.

I'm really struggling to even put together an attempt on this!

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 12652
            [order_date] => 21-01
            [total] => 6.7
            [cumulative] => 6.7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 5204
            [order_date] => 21-02
            [total] => 21.65
            [cumulative] => 28.35
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 7270
            [order_date] => 21-02
            [total] => 10.98
            [cumulative] => 39.33
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 0
            [order_date] => 21-03
            [total] => 0
            [cumulative] => 39.33
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 196331
            [order_date] => 21-04
            [total] => 12.6
            [cumulative] => 51.93
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 199875
            [order_date] => 21-04
            [total] => 14.75
            [cumulative] => 66.68
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 0
            [order_date] => 21-05
            [total] => 0
            [cumulative] => 66.68
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 0
            [order_date] => 21-06
            [total] => 0
            [cumulative] => 66.68
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 0
            [order_date] => 21-07
            [total] => 0
            [cumulative] => 66.68
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 0
            [order_date] => 21-08
            [total] => 0
            [cumulative] => 66.68
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 0
            [order_date] => 21-09
            [total] => 0
            [cumulative] => 66.68
        )

    [total] => 66.68
    [orders] => 5
    [avg] => 13.336
)
```

Comment: The fact that you have a mixture of key types / data types here makes this a little more complicated, but not by that much. Get the keys of the array, and filter out only those that are numeric. Then loop over those in reverse order. Check if the order date of the current item is already contained in a helper array where you stored the ones you already encountered - if so, then the item at that current key needs to be unset.

Comment: use `var_export` when posting result in array, so they can be easily used while duplicating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first invert your array with `array_reverse()` and then walk through each element in array with `array_filter` while checking whether the key has appeared before or not. if false returned inside the array_filter callback function, that element would be filtered out.

Here is the code:

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'order_id' => '12652',
        'order_date' => '21-01',
        'total' => 6.7,
        'cumulative' => 6.7
    ),
    array(
        'order_id' => 5204,
        'order_date' => '21-02',
        'total' => 21.65,
        'cumulative' => 28.35
    ),

    array(
        'order_id' => 7270,
        'order_date' => '21-02',
        'total' => 10.98,
        'cumulative' => 39.33,
    ),

    array(
        'order_id' => 0,
        'order_date' => '21-03',
        'total' => 0,
        'cumulative' => 39.33
    ),

    array(
        'order_id' => 196331,
        'order_date' => '21-04',
        'total' => 12.6,
        'cumulative' => 51.93
    ),

    array(
        'order_id' => 199875,
        'order_date' => '21-04',
        'total' => 14.75,
        'cumulative' => 66.68
    ),

    array(
        'order_id' => 0,
        'order_date' => '21-05',
        'total' => 0,
        'cumulative' => 66.68
    ),

    array(
        'order_id' => 0,
        'order_date' => '21-06',
        'total' => 0,
        'cumulative' => 66.68
    ),

    array(
        'order_id' => 0,
        'order_date' => '21-07',
        'total' => 0,
        'cumulative' => 66.68
    ),

    array(
        'order_id' => 0,
        'order_date' => '21-08',
        'total' => 0,
        'cumulative' => 66.68
    ),

    array(
        'order_id' => 0,
        'order_date' => '21-09',
        'total' => 0,
        'cumulative' => 66.68
    ),

    'total' => 66.68,
    'orders' => 5,
    'avg' => 13.336,
);

echo '<pre>';
$res = array_filter(array_reverse($arr), function ($item) {
    static $existentKeys = [];
    if (isset($item['order_date'])) {
        $order_date = $item['order_date'];
    }
    if (isset($order_date) && isset($existentKeys[$order_date])) {
        return false;
    } elseif (isset($order_date)) {
        $existentKeys[$order_date] = true;
        return $item;
    }
    return $item;
});
print_r(array_reverse($res));
```

Comment: That worked a treat, thanks so much